# Plotting a 3D Meshgrid:

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, spyder

I am using Spyder Interface (Python 2.7) to numerically solve PDE's.  I have the code set up to where U is calculated with respect to position, and time.  U is a [nxm] matrix in my code where n is position and m is time.  So at each U[n,m] the code gives a nth position at a mth time.  Is there a way I can make use of a such matrix to make a mesh plot in python.  I have searched, but for example numpy's mesh grid only deals with arrays.  Thank you.

```
[[ 1.20643447  1.20520185  1.20397894 ...,  1.04589795  1.04587534 1.04585286]
[ 1.40901699  1.40658211  1.4041664  ...,  1.09172525  1.09168043 1.09163586]
[ 1.6039905   1.6004133   1.59686428 ...,  1.13741248  1.13734625 1.1372804 ]..., 
[ 2.3960095   2.3995867   2.40313572 ...,  2.54969453  2.55003659 2.55037764]
[ 2.59098301  2.59341789  2.57981471 ...,  2.59750546  2.59785406 2.59820163]
[ 2.79356553  2.74473913  2.71231633 ...,  2.64640578  2.64675767 2.64710852]]
```

These are the many values for  U the shell spits at me.  As you can see I would be dealing with 600 different arrays because the matrix is set up to find U at at specific time and position.  Taking a total of 600 time steps.
[image: This is a example of a type of graph that I am trying to reproduce.]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't, prior to plotting, convert the matrix to an array, with `np.asarray(U)` or `np.array(U)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to use the search function; you can find working code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766536/matplotlib-3d-surface-from-a-rectangular-array-of-heights) among many other threads on plotting surfaces here on Overflow.

---

I think you might have some terminology mix up here. You have a matrix of values which correspond to the values of a function of two dimensions; this is not a meshgrid. In `matplotlib` you can visualize a three-dimensional matrix in a number of ways, typically as a [`surface`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots), a [`wireframe`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots), or an [`image`](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) (as a heatmap).

The function [`np.meshgrid()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) gives you `N`-dimensional indices. You need this for your `n` and `m` vectors, not your matrix `U`, to turn them into multidimensional arrays the same shape as your matrix. Luckily for you, `matplotlib` doesn't care whether `U` is a matrix or a vector.

For example with `np.meshgrid()`:

```
>>> t = np.linspace(0,60,6000)
>>> x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,3600)
>>> T, X = np.meshgrid(t, x)
>>> t.shape
(6000,)
>>> x.shape
(3600,)
>>> T.shape
(3600, 6000)
>>> X.shape
(3600, 6000)
```

And now to create a function `U(x,t)`:

```
>>> U = np.matrix(x[:, np.newaxis] * t) # broadcast
>>> U.shape
(3600, 6000)
```

And to plot the surface, you can use the `surf` function in `Axes3D` from `matplotlib` for example, but you can also use the wireframe or image method linked above.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import pylab
>>> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
>>> surf = ax.plot_surface(X,T,U)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: Surface plot]

Comment: So in my case.  I can just put U into the 3-D surface plot with pyplot even though it is a 2-D array it should still work?  Because after setting my mesh for X and T I got a shape mismatch value error.  When including U.

Comment: You probably just have `X` and `T` backwards in your array---I wasn't being particularly faithful to your exact array. Just print the shapes out as you go like I did, and you'll get more comfortable with the relationships between the numpy shapes. It's a little confusing at first, but mostly intuitive. You want the meshgrids to be the same shape as your matrix.

Comment: You were right I checked the shapes of U, X, and T and they did not work properly.  Then I changed the meshgrid format, and it worked perfectly.  Thanks for your help.